# How to release a view object after adding it as a subView: Fixing memory leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have created a `UILabel` locally and added it as a `subview` to my view.
The following problems arise:
1) Performing `"Analyze"` the compiler shows a `"incorrect decrement of the reference count of the object"`
2) I observe the retain count is not zero.
This is my code:

```
-(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)rect labelText:(NSString *)labelText {
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
label.text = labelText;
return label;
}
- (void)initMyView {
UILabel *label = [self createLabel:rect labelText:circuitName];
NSLog(@"before using %d", [label retainCount]);
[self.heatingCircuitsScrollView addSubview:label];
NSLog(@"before release %d", [label retainCount]);
[label release];
NSLog(@"After release %d", [label retainCount])
}
```

I get the following in my console:

**before using 1
before release 2
After release 1**

I know that using Autorelease on the `"createlabel"` method  solves the problem. I want to know which is the **best approach** and how to release a object once its added to the Subview.

Comment: No opinion on either of the answers you've got? I can clarify, if you've got questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static analyser sees you releasing an object that is returned from a method called `create...`. It therefore assumes that you do not have an owning reference to the returned object.

If your method was called `newLabel...` instead, the warning would go away, because methods beginning with `new` (or `alloc` or `copy`) are assumed to create an object which the caller is responsible for releasing. All other methods are assumed to return autoreleased objects.

Comment: I highly doubt that 'Analyze' takes the function name into account.

Comment: Thank you. Yes _Analyze_ does check the function name. its the right way. It removed the warning. But still the retain counts remains as 1 as mentioned above. Isn't that a leak?

Comment: Retain count isn't your problem and shouldn't be used for anything. A view retains its subviews, so you'd expect the label still to be retained. All you need to do is balance your allocations and your releases (or switch to ARC)

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should be a somewhat correct code. The issue here rests with the function call. Analyze sees: 'alloc without release' and alerts you of that.

Try using 'alloc' -> 'init' -> 'autorelease'. That way, the object will get released the moment you're not using it any more. You're returning it by the function, which will tell the compiler, that you're still using it and would clean it up only after the end of the function the function is called in ends, if not for the adding to the subview.

The subview will 'release' it's object, when the subview itself is destroyed.

To make the long story short:

Add autorelease to the alloc and remove the release from the calling method.
That should solve your problem.

Comment: The questioner already knows that autorelease solves the warning, they would like to know _why_

Comment: @jrturton And I told him why. Because there's an alloc without release in the function call, and release without alloc.

Comment: @ATaylor Thanks for the info, that was helpful. yes I think _autorelease_ is the solution and I knew that. But was curious to know the logical way why the "Analyze" tools throws that error.